# XMonad, `spawnOn` order

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I have the following in my `xmonad.hs`:

```hs
spawnOnOnce "0" "kitty -e vim ~/configuration.org; kitty"
spawnOnOnce "0" "kitty"
```

And it works, but the thing is, the order of the execution is always different: sometimes the first "spawn" is executed and sometime the second. I need the order of execution to be always the same, e.g., in the order they are written.

Please help :-)

#### EDIT 1:

As per @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica request in the comments below:

> Why does it matter the exact order in which the processes are spawned?

I use the "Master/Stack" layout (with `manageHook = insertPosition End Newer ...`), and if the second "spawnOn" is the first to be executed, then it would be on the left side of the screen, I want it to be always on the right side of the screen.

Comment: Why does it matter the exact order in which the processes are spawned? Remember that it's possible the first child won't be scheduled until after the second one is fully initialized and running.

Comment: Thank you very much @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica for your comment. I've updated the OP to answer your question.

Comment: As a test, put `sleep 5; ` at the beginning of one of the command lines. Does the one you do that to always end up on the right side of the screen? If so, then you're indeed relying on a race condition, and your real question should be how to make window layout depend on something other than their order of creation.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Your suggestion about `sleep 5;` will probably work (I will try it asap). But, it feels like a hack :-)

Comment: It is a hack. That's why I'm saying to just do it as a test and not to keep it as your solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that `spawnOnOnce` does not make guarantees about execution order.

You could probably get around this by having the first command upon completion send a `SIGUSR2` signal to the xmonad process, and having the second command wait for that `SIGUSR2` signal.

Proof of concept (untested):

```hs
spawnOnOnce "0" "kitty -e vim ~/configuration.org; kitty; pkill --SIGUSR2 xmonad"
void $ installHandler sigUSR2 (CatchOnce $ spawnOnOnce "0" "kitty") Nothing
```

Where `installHandler`, `sigUSR2`, and `CatchOnce` come from `System.Posix.Signals`.

Since `kitty` is a terminal, this may not work, since the `pkill --SIGUSR2` may not be executed until `kitty` is closed. So, you may have to play around with that: `pkill --SIGUSR2 xmonad & kitty` might work, or `kitty & pkill --SIGUSR2 xmonad; wait`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it asap, it will probably work. But, the solution feels like a hack :-) Is not there some kind of call back one can pass to `spawnOnOnce`?

Comment: @RefaelSheinker I don't know of such a thing, but also, I've never needed one :-p